# QtCreator + Visual Studio 2010 compile = link error (SysAllocString@4)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt, qt4, qt-creator, qmake

I am using Visual Studio with a couple of Qt4 projects and I would like to switch to QtCreator, but keeping the msvc compiler.

After configuring everything in QtCreator I get this linker error:

> LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _imp_SysAllocString@4

Any idea about what is going on? I don't get this error if I compile using Visual Studio.

Comment: Are you linking against OleAut32.dll? Could you please show the verbose building output? Also, are you using release build or debug?

Comment: Thank you! adding LIBS+= -loleaut32 -lole32 to my .pro files solved the issue, but Why don't I need them if I compile with visual studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to link against OleAut32.dll. Try adding this to your qmake project file:

```
win32: LIBS += -loleaut32 -lole32
```

Comment: Thanks, it solves the issue, but I don't understand why this is not needed if I compile using Visual Studio

Comment: @louissmr: Because you specify that differently in there AFAIK. You use the UI and project settings for that, or it may be included by default, or just simply forgot that it has already been put into the build system.

Comment: I create the visual studio projects using qmake from my .pro files, maybe is added by default, thank you.

Comment: @louissmr: strange, are you using the Qt plugin for VS? Are you using the same toolchain in both cases?

Comment: No and no. In QtCreator the build is driven by nmake (or jom) using makefiles.

Comment: @louissmr: you should have used the qt plugin. OK, so you are using the same toolchain then. I would think your VS buildsystem files (.sln/.vcsproj) contain this linkage or the project settings, or somehow it is defined by VS automatically. I cannot be sure.